# Offline Android OCR receipt scanner

Tags: android, offline, ocr, scanning

I have been looking for an Android receipt scanner that does NOT upload data to the providers servers.

I'm looking for a solution that will process photos of receipts and use OCR to extract data stored on the device/phone.  A nice to have ability would be to export this data as Excel or even CSV.

So far all the apps I have seen/found require an account and upload data to the cloud.

Comment: Must the app be free, or how much would you be willing to pay? Also, while waiting for answers, please take a look at my list of apps for [Shopping Receipts](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/shopping_receipts).

Comment: Try using **Text Fairy** app. Maybe it can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tool for Android : [PDF Scanner:Document Scan+ OCR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grymala.photoscannerpdftrial&hl=en)

It does local processing as stated :

> 2) Built-in OCR system (50 languages supported). Extract text from
>   images. All processing is performed locally right on user’s device,
>   even without network connection

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ScanBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.doo.snap)

It has a free version that does NOT OCR, and a paid one that does. It OPTIONALLY automatically uploads all scans to a cloud service of your choice, in case that is beneficial to you.

Not sure about  where OCR processing is done, though. The info in the app store does not tell about this.